# Bootstrap two column layout - align fields in nested column with text area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Forgive me, I'm rather new to Bootstrap 3.

What is the best way to achieve the proposed layout using Bootstrap 3's grid 24 CSS? In particular, the text area (Project Description) and the fields in the nested column to its right (Reason Code, Priority, and Class) are proving to be a challenge. I don't think I quite understand how column and field widths are inherited in the grid.

See [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/VnJKdVYXPd) for an example, aligning the Reason Code, Priority, and Class fields as closely as I could, which obviously needs a bit of tweaking.

[image]

Comment: Hello @TimeBomb, I am a bit confused on what you would like to achieve. Maybe post this in a http://www.bootply.com/new?

Comment: @MichaelJones Sorry about that. I've modified my question and included the BootPly link. Basically, the goal is to have the Project Description text area align with the three fields to its right, while also having the Reason Code, Priority, and Class labels and inputs aligned correctly. Am I over-complicating it?

Comment: Sorry @TimeBomb, I didn't have time to reply. It seems like you have gotten many helpful answers though! :) If you would like another answer, and some more help, feel free to ask, and I will post one myself. That way I can best possibly answer all questions that you may have.

Answer (score 1):

According to the snap shot, First you have to divide row > col into 3

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             //Here comes Input
             //Here comes Input
             //Here comes Textarea
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             //Here comes Select
             //Here comes Select
             //Here comes Select
             //Here comes Select
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             //Here comes Picture
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In each col, you can do like this to align label in front of input, select or text-area (inline style)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectName" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblProjectName" class="control-label">Project Name</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectName" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problems in your code;

1. You don't need to write own css `form-control-inline`, you can simply divide the cols as like in 2nd code to achieve that what you are tying to achieve with `form-control-inline` and thn you also don't need this `col-md-4` in `<label>` class
2. You don't need to `style="height:65px;"` the text area like this, just set the number of rows and it will adjust the height itself like `<textarea class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>`

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll re-write it based on your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution of your problem. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/zp8r8f94/1/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectName" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblProjectName">Project Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-inline col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblActivityType">Activity Type</label>
                <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" class="form-control-inline col-md-3 col-xs-6"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectName" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblProjectName">Project Launch</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-inline col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblActivityType">Status</label>
                <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" class="form-control-inline col-md-3 col-xs-6"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-6 col-xs-12">Project Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control-inline col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="height:75px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-6 col-xs-6">Reason Code</label>
                            <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" class="form-control-inline col-md-6 col-xs-6"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-6 col-xs-6">Priority</label>
                            <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" class="form-control-inline col-md-6 col-xs-6"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-6 col-xs-6">Class</label>
                            <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" class="form-control-inline col-md-6 col-xs-6"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">Test image here
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

P.S. I only added the bootstrap classes for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I made some corrections in the code, to arrive at the goal of the draft you presented, but the basic Bootstrap basically already provides.

What I realized that you have not mastered the grid is that to get the perfect alignment, columns side by side have to add a final value of 24, for example: al-lg-14 next to al-lg-10. If you use the lg variations, md, and xs sm, you can control how the layout will behave in various screen resolutions.

**HTML**

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-18 col-md-18 col-xs-24">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-24">
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectName" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblProjectName" class="control-label col-md-10">Project Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-14">
                <input type="text" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectName" class="form-control-inline form-left">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectLaunchName" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblProjectLaunchName" class="control-label col-md-10">Project Launch Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-14">
                <input name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$txtProjectLaunchName" type="text" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_txtProjectLaunchName" class="form-control-inline form-left">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label class="control-label col-md-10">Project Description</label>
              <div class="col-md-14">
                <textarea class="form-control-inline form-left" style="height:65px;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-24">
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblActivityType" class="control-label col-md-8">Activity Type</label>
              <div class="col-md-16">
                <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlActivityType" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlActivityType" disabled="disabled" class="form-control-inline">
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label for="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlStatus" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_lblStatus" class="control-label col-md-8">Status</label>
              <div class="col-md-16">
                <select name="ctl00$CP1$ProjectDetail$ddlStatus" id="ctl00_CP1_ProjectDetail_ddlStatus" class="form-control-inline validationpurple">
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label class="control-label col-md-8">Reason Code</label>
              <div class="col-md-16">
                <input type="text" class="form-control-inline">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label class="control-label col-md-8">Priority</label>
              <div class="col-md-16">
                <input type="text" class="form-control-inline">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row space-form">
              <label class="control-label col-md-8">Class</label>
              <div class="col-md-16">
                <input type="text" class="form-control-inline">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-24 ">
          <div class="well space-form" style="height: 100%">Test image here <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
        .space-form {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .control-label {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .form-control-inline {
        width: 100%
    }
    @media (max-width:991px) {
    .form-left {
        width: 100%
    }
    }
    @media (min-width:990px) {
    .form-left {
        width: 90%
    }
    }
```